# Maximum window size changes from PC to PC

Tags: c#

I created a small test application which allows very limited functionality of copying files from one place to another. Now due to the limited functionality, I kept the window size fixed (having maximized as false and well defined height and width of 250x200 pixels). Just 2 file browse elements  and a Copy button.

My friends test ran it on their PCs and the problem is that it ran all well for most of my friends, however 3 of them noticed that the height of the application was not enough and the copy button was 80% hidden (only 20% of it was visible). One of them was on a 1920x1080 resolution and the other 2 were on 1366x728. And all the test PCs were Windows 7 computers.

How and why would this possibly happen?

Comment: What code are you using to define the height. Kinda hard to help or reproduce an error without a sample.

Comment: this depends on the OS settings (like font sizes, theme etc.).

Comment: Check out the different machines' DPI settings, in Windows 7 under "Make text and other items bigger or smaller". This is a common problem, especially with non-DPI aware platforms like WinForms, that don't scale properly.

Comment: I would ask for screen-shots from them all, for comparing.

Comment: Its the DPI settings as pointed out by Mark (see answer below). Now the point is to figure out a fix for this as the end user might have 100%, 125%, 150% or 200% as the magnification value in the dpi settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that I can think of one is their  DPI setting's are different than your computer.

> Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display

[image]

Comment: bingo.. this is the actual problem! All my 3 friends confirmed that they can now see the copy button. Well, I can't say that it is a problem - users can keep whatever kind of display they want! The problem is for me to work around this and still show things correctly. Any pointers on how a fix for this could possibly be achieved? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Rohan I would use the Form's [AutoScaleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode) like Hans suggests

Answer (score 1):

> having maximized as false and well defined height and width of 250x200 pixels

That's fine, as long as you set this size *only* in the form constructor.  And set the FormBorderStyle to Fixed so it is clear that the window cannot be resized.  If you do it later, like in the Load or Resize event then you'll displease users that have a nice high-resolution display.  Or a "retina" display, we'll all have them soon.  They need to bump up the video adapter's dot-per-inch setting so they can still read 8 point text without a magnifying glass.

Which causes text to get rendered with more pixels.  Which requires that your controls get bigger, their sizes are specified in pixels.  If you don't let them grow then you'll have small controls with big text, unattractive and unreadable.  Bigger controls in turn requires that they move and that your form gets bigger so it still fits the controls.

This is all automatic, thanks to the form's AutoScaleMode setting.  It defaults to Font which is just what you need.  But that can't work when you force the form back to its original design size, it will clip the moved controls.

A quick way to check if your form still works properly on such a machine, other than tinkering with the video dpi setting, is this bit of test code in the Load event handler:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, this.Font.Size * 125 / 96f);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```